# jquery hover scroll bar not working with hover

Tags: jquery

I am making a simple scroll bar with jquery for learning. But it is running only one time when hover. how to fix it? here is my snippest:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.scrollbar').hover(function(e){
    var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    $(this).children('.scroll-but').css({
      'top': y + 'px'
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.scrollbar{
  position:relative;
  width:10px;
  height:500px;
  background:red;
}
.scroll-but{
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:blue;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollbar"><div class="scroll-but"></div></div>
```

Comment: Instead of `.hover` use `.mousemove`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the event handler being attached is `.hover` the function runs only when an hover event is triggered, another hover event won't be fired if you move your mouse inside of the target element.

To do that you have to use the `.mousemove` event, it tracks the pointer as it moves on the target element and gives you the expected results.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.scrollbar').mousemove(function(e){
    var y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    $(this).children('.scroll-but').css({
      'top': y + 'px'
    });
  })
});
```

```css
.scrollbar{
  position:relative;
  width:10px;
  height:500px;
  background:red;
}
.scroll-but{
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:blue;
  right:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollbar"><div class="scroll-but"></div></div>
```